# Using TransactionScope with Entity Framework code first and universal providers

Tags: asp.net-membership, transactionscope

I'm trying to set up a transaction where my code creates a new user using the membership provider and then goes on to create an object and put it into one of my Entity Framework tables.  If the EF operation fails, I want to be able to rollback to before the user was created.  I have a single connection string for both EF and membership, so I think both operations should be using the same sql connection.

When I first run it, I get an

> "MSDTC on server ... is unavailable."

exception on the Membership.CreateUser line.  When I start the DTC service, I get an

> "The underlying provider failed on open"

exception with an inner exception

> "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction."

on the same line.  If I change the order around and do the EF save first and then the membership, the EF part works, but CreateUser fails with the same exceptions.

It seems like 2 sql connections are being used even though I have one connection string.  Is there a way to force both the membership and EF operations to use the same connection or is there some other way to put this inside of a transaction?

Here's the code

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.UserName, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

    //add objects to the DbContext db

    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
```

Answer (score 0):

As u say even u use the same connection string for both EF and membership they use different connections then transaction scope automatically escalating to DTC

And as far i know for use same connection for both

> it is not possible to put a custom connection into the SqlMembershipProvider
>
> according to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/6a61bcec-7ea3-43a7-862f-79e83c32bc9c)

to avoid involving DTC